# Are some numbers more equidistributed than others?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Weyl's theorem says that $n\alpha$ is equidistributed mod 1 for any irrational $\alpha$.  One corollary is that, if I consider the fractional part $\{n\alpha\}$ for $n \leq N$, and look at the indices $n_k$ where it's small ($\{n_k \alpha\} \leq \epsilon$), the number of such indices $K$ will be approximately equal $N\epsilon$ as $N \to \infty$.  In other words, if I look at the spacings between the consecutive integers $n_k$ where $n_k \cdot \alpha$ is nearly an integer, the mean spacing will be close to $N\epsilon$.

Can anything interesting be said about the variance of the spacing?  For example, if $\alpha \approx 1/N$, the numbers $n_k$ will be $1, 2, \dotsc, N\epsilon$, so the spacings are all 1 except for one enormous spacing of size $N-\epsilon$, and the variance of the spacings will be $O(N)$.  But this is cheating, since I picked $\alpha$ to depend on $N$.  Are there any results on the asymptotics of this for fixed irrational $\alpha$?  Are some values clumpier than others, or does it all wash out as you let $N \to \infty$?

Comment: Doesn't your argument show the mean spacing is close to $1/(2 \epsilon)$?

Comment: Maybe look up "discrepancy". Oh, there's also a nice result saying there are at most $3$ distinct return times to any interval, for any given $\alpha$. I think the golden ratio has those return times the most regular.

Comment: not that conversant with the fine details on this topic, but I know that lots of stuff about the variance above depends on the continued fraction representation of $\alpha$; for quadratic irrationals there are explicit central limit theorems; the book Probabilistic Diophantine Approximations by J Beck has a lot of stuff on the behavior of the irrational rotations and explains why the quadratics and related irrationals with small continued fraction approximations terms like $e$ have the most "anti-rational" behavior; see https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-10741-7

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: Perhaps you can apply some results from geometry of numbers to the set $\{(x,y) \mid |x| \leq N+\frac12, |\alpha x - y| \leq \epsilon\}$, like how you can use Minkowski's theorem to prove Dirichlet's approximation theorem

Comment: Fractional part is between zero and one, so you don't need to take absolute values (that is, you can write $\{n_k\alpha\}$ instead of $|\{n_k\alpha\}|$).

Comment: Nice Orwellian question title

Comment: @mathworker21: this looks like exactly what I was looking for, can you elaborate?  The Wikipedia article on discrepancy theory convinced me that it would be a valid tag, but didn't actually give useful results to look at.

Comment: @ElenaYudovina I don't know about your variance question specifically (besides the second part of my comment). I just mentioned "discrepancy" because it seemed to answer the title of your post. A book on uniform distribution and discrepancy that is very good and has many, many results is "uniform distribution of sequences" by Kuipers and Niederreiter.

Comment: @mathworker21 Do you have a reference for the second half of your comment / some way to formalize what you mean by "most regular"?

Answer (score 2):

Given $\alpha$ and $\varepsilon = 1/N$, fix  $k\gg N$ such that $ 
 \lbrace  k\alpha \rbrace  \ll \varepsilon $.  Now if we consider the sequence $\bar s_0 := (kn\alpha:n\in \mathbb N)$, which is a subsequence of the original sequence along an arithmetic sequence of indices, this new sequence behaves just like the example you gave for a small $\alpha$.

If we let $\bar s_i := ((kn+i)\alpha:n\in \mathbb N)$ for $i=0,\dots,k-1$, then each of these sequences is just a shifted copy of $\bar s_0$ and has therefore the same behavior. (e.g. same variance)

We can divide the original sequence into blocks of length $k$.  For each such block $(nk\alpha, (nk+1)\alpha, \dots, (nk+k-1)\alpha)$, consider the interval $[a,b)$, where $a\in [0,1)$ is $nk\alpha$ mod 1, and $b\in[1,2)$ is $(n+1)k\alpha $ mod 1.  Then $b-a\approx 1$, and the $k$ entries in our block divide the interval [a,b) into $k$ equal pieces of length $1/k$ each. (almost)

The whole sequence $(n\alpha)$ is now a finite union of sequences $\bar s_i:=((kn+i)\alpha:n\in \mathbb N)$, for $i=0,\dots, k-1$.

So for each $n$, you will get a set $M_n$ of (approximately) $2k\varepsilon$ distinct indices $i_1(n),\dots, i_{2k\varepsilon}$ in $\{1,\dots, k\}$ such that all the values $(kn+i_j(n))\alpha$ are close to $0$, and the others are not.    I think that any behavior (such as the variance) of the sequence $n\alpha $ mod 1 can now be reduced to the behavior of the sequence $nk\alpha$, up to a factor depending on $k$, which is constant (depending on $\varepsilon$, of course).